# Cordova error: could not find cordova as a local module

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

When I run this command in the terminal to run the emulator:

```
ripple emulate
```

it gives me an error like this:

> could not find cordova as a local module ...

Please help me. I am new to cordova and phonegap.

Comment: First, upgrade question with some syntax highlight in terms of better readibility.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use:

```
ionic run android
```

it could open the Android Emulator, then install and run your Ionic app.

Comment: it's an [Ionic CLI command](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/run.html), so it's available if Ionic Framework is correctly installed in your project